# How to configure Node-RED from behind proxy

Tags: ibm-cloud, node-red

I'm trying to run Node-RED on IBM Bluemix from pc that is behind http/https proxy.

In case with proxy, I encounter the error 'Lost connection to server, reconnecting in 10s'

How can we run our Node-RED from behind proxy?

Comment: How are you accessing the Node-RED instance, http or https?

Comment: I was accessing http.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely because the proxy is dropping the WebSockets connection to the Node-RED instance on Bluemix.

Try making sure you are accessing the Node-RED instance via HTTPS as this is likely to tunnel the entire connection between the browser and the server via a HTTP Connect call which has been shown in the past to be more stable.